# Json-server returning 404 when accessing custom route

Tags: json, json-server

I'm trying to use `json-server` with custom routes, but they're all returning a 404.I can see that the `routes.json` file is being read, as well as the `db.json` file.

Here's the output from running json-server:

```
  Resources
  http://localhost:8000/check
  http://localhost:8000/custom-route

  Other routes
  /custom-route/me/ -> /custom-route

  Home
  http://localhost:8000

GET /check 304 2.994 ms - -
GET /custom-route/me/ 404 2.363 ms - 2
```

As you can see, json-server understands the custom route but it's not translating it. In the case of `/custom-route/me`, all I want is for it to end up in the same path, just without the `/me`.

Here's `routes.json`:

```
{
  "/custom-route/me/": "/custom-route"
}
```

And here's the part of `db.json` that refers to `/custom-route`:

```
  "custom-route": {
    "response": "check"
  },
```

What's going on and how can I fix it?